# jquery ajax calls in an mvc site not sharing logged in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

as in the title

we're firing

```
$('#id').load('someUrl', function(){/*some stuff*/});
```

But it seems to be being passed to the login form because it's not logged in?!

The user is logged in. Is this normal?

Comment: This should work. AJAX requests send all necessary cookies. Maybe the session expired?

Comment: What error/response are you getting back?

Comment: Is the request being sent to the same domain? What does the URL point at? Is it an MVC action, an asmx web service, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too, but the cause was not that ajax is going crazy - which it may look like - but that the URL was not correct.

The website was initially hosted on localhost, without any alias, so I had a working URL like localhost/controller/action.

Then I moved the website under an alias - so the website's URL was localhost/alias. At this point, two strange things happaned to SOME ajax requests: 
- the requests were prompted for authentication (the website was using windows authentication)
- the requests' session was different than the one of the page which launched the request

The problem was that some URLs were hardcoded in the js code. So we had code like "`url: '/controller/action'`" in the ajax calls code, and this URL didn't take into consideration the alias under which the website was hosted in IIS.

The solution was to declare a js variable in the page and assign it the URL built the right way, with Url.Action, and then use the variable in the ajax call:
Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("actionname", "controllername")';
</script>
```

Js file:

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxUrl,
...
```